# Upper bounds for coefficients in taylor's series

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, upper-lower-bounds

Let $y=f(x)$ be a real-analytic function defined on $ U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and $B(0.r)\subset U$, where $r>0$ is fixed, and

$$
B(0,r)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: |x|<r\}.
$$

Assume $f(0)=0$, we can write

$$
f(x)=\sum_{\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^n}a_\alpha x^\alpha.
$$

I want to know that, if $|f|\leq M$ on $B(0,r)$, then the upper bounds

$$
|a_\alpha|\leq \frac{M}{r^{|\alpha|}}
$$

holds for all multi-index $\alpha$ ?

Maybe $f(x)=\sin x$ is a counterexample? In this case $f'(0)=1$ but for any $r\in (0,1)$, $|\sin r|/r<1$.

(How to post this question make sense?)

(I only know in the case of several complex variables it is true and is known as Cauchy's inequality.)

This question is from Lemma 6.1.1 in Krantz's book of the implicit function theorem, Page 118. See https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-5981-1

I do not know if it is conflict.

[image]

Comment: You can extend $F$ to a complex analytic function by letting $x$ and $y$ be complex variables, and then apply the Cauchy's inequality.

Comment: @Kakashi But if I extend, then the value of upper bound $K$ maybe changed? I may get the conclusion with a new $M=||F||_\infty$, where $F$ is the complex analytic after extended.

Comment: For example, let $f(x)=\sin x$ then $1>|\sin r|/r$ for $r\in (0,1)$, and let $F(z)=\sin z$, $|z|<r,z\in\mathbb{C}$, then $1<||\sin z||_\infty/|z|$.

Comment: @cbi I think the theorem is false. If it were true, then any bounded real analytic function that converges on all of $\mathbb{R}$ would be $0$ since $|a_n| \leq K R^{-n}$ for all $R > 0$. But $\sin(x)$ is an example that isn't $0$.

Comment: @Mason you are right.

Comment: @Mason then what about the lemma in Krantz's book?